# get a new Properties Settings file in SharpDevelop

Tags: c#, sharpdevelop

If I search here and on other forums how to add a Settings file in SharpDevelop IDE (I use v4.3, installed it when it was new, no need so far for updates), I only find posts of 5+ years ago which state that there's no settings editor in SharpDevelop.

I have an existing solution folder from another project which has a settings file (it's used there for setting default values of some text boxes), and I can edit it in SharpDevelop without problems - so it's built-in now, obviously.

But, how to add a settings file if there's none so far? I can't see an option where to add it, can't find anything in the www for this. Can't be that difficult ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharpDevelop 4 includes a settings file template.

1. Right click the project in the Projects window and select Add - New Item to open the New File dialog.
2. Open the category Misc.
3. There should be a Settings template available.

Comment: Thanks, I found the settings template, but when I add it in the Properties folder (like in the existing project), I just have the settings file there and namespace `MainForm` has no (sub) namespace `Properties`. The existing project has also a file `settings.Designer.cs` that seem to be needed to use the settings file (e.g. for saving the settings with `MainForm.Properties.Settings.Default.Save()`. So how do I get both of these files in SharpDevelop to use them as I can do it in VS? Thanks

Comment: As an additional note: it's sufficient to add one value to the settings file, save it and compile ... that easy

Comment: In my case it helped to choose different name than Settings.settings for the settings file.